# There exists a function dense in $\mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove by transfinite induction that there is a function $f:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ such that $|f^{-1}(r) \bigcap (a,b)| = 2^{\omega}$ for every $a, b, r \in\mathbb R$ and $a < b$.

I have:

Let $F = \{(a,b) \times \{r\}\, |\, a, b, r \in\mathbb R\text{ and }a < b\}$ and $\{F_\xi\, |\, \xi < 2^{\omega}\}$ be an enumeration of $F$.

Also, I have that $(x_\xi, y_\xi) \in F_\xi \setminus \bigcup_{\zeta < \xi} (\{x_\zeta\} \times\mathbb R)$ where $f(x_\xi) = y_\xi$ for all $\xi < 2^{\omega}$.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @Emanuele: $\omega$, if anything. And it's a common notation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila is right.

Comment: Remember, $F_{\xi} = ((a, b), r)$ is a promise that at stage $\xi$, you are going to map a new real in $(a, b)$ to $r$ so choose a new $x_{\xi} \in (a, b)$ and put $f(x_{\xi}) = r$. This can be done since you have only defined $f$ at less than continuum inputs and $(a, b)$ has continuum points.

Comment: So with my proof, I need to ensure that after the $\xi$-step, I have a real in the domain of an already constructed f, and since ($x_\xi , y_\xi$) exists in $F_\xi$ I need to make sure that I don't have another r $=$ $x_\xi$ so that I maintain f as a function. Is this correct?

Comment: You're probably better off forgetting about the enumeration of $(x_\xi,y_\xi)$ (but keeping the enumeration of $F_\xi$), and then following hot_queen's suggestion. At stage $\xi$, if $F_\xi=(a,b)\times\{r\}$, pick a point in $(a,b)$ that isn't already in the domain of the function you're constructing, and put it into the domain, giving your function a value of $r$ there.

Comment: So, am I correct in thinking that F$_\xi$ is dense in R, given that for all $x \in$ F$_\xi$ \ $\bigcup_{\xi < 2^{w}}$ f(x) = r. Which would cause |f$^{-1}$(r) $\bigcap$ (a, b)|  = 2$^{w}$.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with. I know it will need cleaned up a bit, but there aren't any major mistakes.

**Proof:**

Let $F = ${(a,b) $\times$ {r} | a, b, r $\in$ R and $a < b$} and {$F_\xi$ | $\xi <$ 2$^{w}$} be an enumeration of $F$. (I can do this because |$F$| $\le$ |R$^{3}$| $=$ 2$^{w}$)

Now, let ($x_\xi$, $y_\xi$) $\in$ $F_\xi$ \ $\bigcup_{\zeta < \xi}$($x_\zeta$ x R) where f($x_\xi$) = $y_\xi$ for all $\xi <$ 2$^{w}$.

($x_\xi$, $y_\xi$) exists because |$\bigcup_{\zeta < \xi}$($x_\zeta$ x R)| $\le$ |R$^{2}$| = 2$^{w}$ and |$F_\xi$| = |$F$| = |R| = 2$^{w}$.

Now {($x_\xi$, $y_\xi$) | $\xi <$ 2$^{w}$} is a partial function.
Therefore, let R = {$r_\xi$ | $\xi <$ 2$^{w}$}. Choose $U_\xi$ = {($x_\xi$, $y_\xi$), ($t_\xi$, $z_\xi$)}.
We know ($x_\xi$, $y_\xi$) $\in$ $F_\xi$ \ {($x$, $y$)| $x \in \bigcup_{\zeta < \xi}${$x_\zeta$, $t_\zeta$}}.

Thus, $r_\xi$ = $\begin{cases} t_\xi & r_\xi \not\in \{(x_\xi, y_\xi) | \xi < 2^{w}\}  \\ arbitrary\>otherwise \end{cases}$

Therefore, there exists a function $F_\xi$ such that |$F_\xi^{-1}$(r) $\bigcap$ (a,b)| = 2$^{w}$ for every a, b, r $\in$ R and a $<$ b.

Answer (score 0):

*This doesn't directly answer your question, but is too long for a comment. For simplicity, I'll work with $[0, 1)\rightarrow [0, 1)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, just to get rid of annoying details about "integer parts", but this is easily fixed.*

It's worth pointing out that transfinite induction is not necessary here. We can come up with explicit, if somewhat ugly, examples.

Here's one:

Say that "the binary expansion" of a real number is its unique binary expansion **not** ending in an infinite string of "$1$"s (just to get around the issue of multiple binary expansions).

Given a real $r\in [0, 1)$, say $r$ is **good** if the string "$11$" appears only *finitely many* times in the binary expansion of $r$. Note that the good reals are dense - for instance, every dyadic rational is good.

Now, given a good real $r$, let $S(r)$ be the infinite binary sequence starting right after the last occrrence of "$11$" in the binary expansion of $r$, and consisting of every *fourth* bit, skipping the first. So,for instance, if $$r=0.011{\color{green}\wr}0{\color{red}0}010{\color{red}1}001{\color{red}0}101{\color{red}0}100{\color{red}1}001{\color{red}0}101...$$ where the "${\color{green}\wr}$" marks the last occurrence of "$11$", we would have $$S(r)=010010...$$

Then we can define $f(r)$ as:

- $f(r)=0$ if $r$ is not good, and
- $f(r)=0.S(r)$ if $r$ is good. Here "$0.S(r)$" is shorthand for the real whose binary expansion is $S(r)$; note that since we don't allow binary expansions ending in all $1$s, $0.S(r)$ is always in $[0, 1)$.

Then given an interval $(a, b)\subseteq [0, 1)$, pick a dyadic rational $s\in (a, b)$ with (terminating) binary expansion $s=0.a_1a_2...a_n$ and $s+2^{-n}<b$, and consider the real $$s'=0.a_1a_2...a_n0b_10i_10b_20i_20b_30i_3...$$ where $r$ has binary expansion $0.b_1b_2b_3...$ and the $i_k$s are any binary digits at all. It's easy to see that $s'\in [0, 1)$ and $f(s')=r$. But:

- $s'\in (a, b)$, since $a<s<s'$ but $s'<s+2^{-n}<b$; and
- there are continuum-many possible choices for the sequence $(i_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$.

So indeed $f^{-1}(r)\cap (a, b)$ has size continuum for any real $r\in [0, 1)$ and nontrivial interval $(a, b)\subseteq [0, 1)$.

---

Replacing "$[0, 1)$" by "$\mathbb{R}$" makes the construction messier, but no mathematically harder.

Comment: Note that this argument does not require the continuum to be well-orderable, and the function produced by this argument is easily seen to be Borel.